# How to indicate in a java regex, 0,1 or many times a carriage return line feed

Tags: java, regex

I have 2 lines (separated by 0, 1 or many crlf), the value of the first line is always "line1", and thanks to this value I try to capture value of the second line.

Everything is working well when there is only one crlf between the 2 lines, but when there is more than one the regex is also capturing the crlf.

This is my regex :

```
(?s)line1\r\n(.*?) ok
```

Basically I was thinking that this regex will work :

```
(?s)line1\r\n*(.*?) ok
```

But it's not, so how can i possibly indicate with the quantifier *, that there can be 0,1 or many crlf.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to capture the \r\n character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there with your pattern. You don't actually need to enable `DOTALL` with `(?s)`. This pattern should suffice:

```
line1(?:\r\n)*(.*)
```

This matches `line1` followed by zero or more `\r\n`, then your second line.

```
String example = "line1\r\n\r\n\r\nline2";    
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("line1(?:\r\n)+(.*)");    
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(example);

if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Prints: `line2`.

Comment: I am not developping in java, I just use a tool developped in java which lets me use regex to parse some pages

Comment: @user2443476 My code is just an example, presumably you can use the pattern I suggest. Please note: this kind of information is *really useful* in your question, if it's going to affect answers!

Answer (score 0):

I would have try like this

```
(?s)line1(\r\n)*(.*)
```

You put * on \n only so new \r\n weren't matching

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> how can i possibly indicate with the quantifier *, that there can be 0,1 or many crlf.

You might want to match any newline symbol sequences with `[\r\n]*`. This will match `\r\n`, `\n`, `\r` any number of times. Your regex can look like `(?s)line1[\r\n]*(.*?)`, then.